# How to redirect domain.com to www.domain.com?

Tags: url, url-rewrite, redirect, htaccess

I have this code in .htaccess

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine on
    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it still appears to be the domain.com

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. In case anyone need it:

I updated the .htaccess file with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect non-www to www urls
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# redirect http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Then I updated the database web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url to [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) and it worked!

Comment: hi there! please consider marking your answer as solution so others can see it too :)

Answer (score 0):

Run the below two commands to change your url

```
php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="http://www.dmain.com/"

php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url-secure="https://www.dmain.com/"
```

Flush the cache

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```